# How can I set up shortlink domain resolution on my home router or within an OS or browser?

Tags: linux, networking, router, dns, google-chrome-os

I work at a large multinational internet firm and internally we have shortlinks that resolve unqualified or partially-qualified domain names into the full domain name as well as allow custom shortlinks to be created. I am looking to implement this at home.

For example, I would like reddit and r/ to resolve to reddit.com, I would like food/ to resolve to https://www.google.com/search?q=food, and router/ to resolve to 192.168.0.1, and so on.

Is there an easy way to implement this? If there is some way to do this in Chrome or Linux or my router I'd love to know.

-David

Comment: You can only partially do this with DNS, and its not a good idea - DNS will only allow you to expand a domain name, not modify the part after the domain name.  Also, because browsers tell the server the domain name entered into them, it will break quite a lot of sites.    You thus are more likely to find the solution by using a proxy or browser plugin.

Comment: A proxy makes a lot of sense. Do you know what I should look for in terms of trying to learn how to configure one for this purpose?

Comment: Sorry, I can't really advise on proxies.  Thinking about this some more, its not trivial, but the way I would (a) configure my nameserver system to return an IP address on my local network for (anything).mydomain and then set up a web server to answer on IP address and consult a lookup table which in turn does a redirect request - ie the focus would not be on on resolving but by answering requests for unknown web sites and redirecting to the correct URL.   I would probably do this with a LAMP/WAMP setup and use hosts file or run a dns server with wildcard dns on a local-only domain.

Comment: @davidgo, interesting suggestion.. I would love to see your answer on setting that up.